# python program using Glade, GObject, runs fine for days, then suddenly all windows are blank

Tags: linux, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gobject

I have a large data acquisition and control program written in Python3.4.2 using GUI mostly developed on Glade 3.18.3, Gtk3.0 GObject running Debian 8 with XFCE.

There are timers that keep doing things, and these work fine. After startup, the program runs for some 3 - 7 days, then suddenly, all of the windows go blank and stay blank. Other applications are not affected. Memory and CPU usage is modest.

There are no indications of problems prior to the windows going blank. The windows show their title bars and respond normally to minimize, restore, move to another Workspace, etc. It looks like they are not getting repainted - no widgets are visible at all. The code is way too large to post here, and I am not able to isolate a specific problem area for lack of obvious symptoms other than the blank screens. There are no error messages or warnings.

The timers continue to run, acquire data and control things. This happens whether the program is run from the command line or under PyDev in Eclipse.

**Things I have tried:**

In the main timer loop, I put code to look for a file, and then exec the command in it, printing the results, so I have been able to mess with the program in real time:
Replace the usual `Gtk.main()` with a while loop whose variable, if not made false, will re-execute the `Gtk.main()`. Executing `Gtk.main.quit()` stops Gtk.main and starts it again. Windows still blank. Did this repeatedly to no avail.

Experimented with garbage collection with GC. Collecting garbage makes no different. Windows still blank.
Put in code to print percent of time consumed by the timer loops. Fairly steady around 18 - 20% of available CPU time, so nothing is hogging the CPU preventing re-paint.

I have a button that clears a label. I read the label, then executed a builder.get_object(...).activate command to the button. I re-read the label and it was now properly blank. So events and widgets appear to be working normally, at least to some extent.

Finally, if I click on the close X on the title bar, XFCE asks me if I want to wait or close now. So it seems as though there may be a disconnection or problem with signals and the OS, even though `XXX.activate()` works.

Web searching is in vain. Does anybody have ideas of what might be happening, useful diagnostics, or other suggestions? Many thanks!

**April 27, 2017 Update:**

I have taken two substantial steps to mostly work around problems. First, partly in response to a couple of Gtk crashes over the last few months, instead of ending the main program with:

```
Gtk.main()
```

I end with:

```
while wannalive:
    try:
        Gtk.main()
    except:
        pass
```

wannalive is True until user does a quit, so recovery is instant.

Second, I grouped all of the code for each window setup and initial population of static items into two functions. I also made another function for closing a window. These functions propagate to children, grandchildren windows. A function in the top window first, closes, then re-creates all windows, with one call. In operation, there are overlaps in what windows exist, but that is not a problem.

Above, I describe that I can inject code with an external program. The external program has a button that injects a call to that third function. In about five seconds or less, the result of a single button click is to replace all blank windows with functional windows. For my purposes in a controlled environment with a trained operator, this is acceptable.

Next, let me address the relationship between the timer loops and GUI events processing. I do use GObject.timeout_add(ms, somefunction). Experiment shows that a button that calls time.sleep(5) stalls the timer. Experiment shows that injecting time.sleep(5) in the timer loop stalls the GUI. This is consistent with my belief (correct me if I am wrong) that Python runs on a single thread. Therefore, bad code caught in an infinite loop should stall both the GUI and the timer loop. (The program has one timeout_add call.)

Comment: Are you checking for errors when the program is running? Say like, running it in the terminal.

Comment: Both my IDE (PyDev in Elcipse) and running in a terminal show results of print statements, errors and warnings. So, yes, if there were any warnings or errors I would have seen them. There are none. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem on a different computer? How about a different Linux distro?

Comment: Good suggestion, but specialized hardware and downtime render it impractical. I would have to build a whole new system. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried running the program under `gdb` and setting a breakpoint on one of the GTK+ widget drawing/allocation functions, like `gtk_widget_real_size_allocate`? You’ll need to install the GTK+ debug symbols first. If that’s being run, then the main repainting loop is not getting blocked — it’s possible that your timers are not in the same main loop as the GTK+ paint loop (are they added using `g_timeout_add()`?) and hence the main loop might be blocked by something even if the timers are still running.

Comment: Philip: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Please see updated, revised post for experiment results. Do you still believe your suggestion to be applicable? Why? (I may need some education here.) Thanks!